# intermediately created by Visual Studio untracked files removal

Tags: git, github

I need to pull new commits into my local dir, but I get an error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Which command I need to use to remove that intermediately created by Visual Studio untracked files from
my local repo? `git checkout`?

Comment: Just delete the files yourself. They're untracked by git, so, just remove them if you don't want them?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the untracked files with

`git clean -f -x -d`

should do the trick.

But the problem you have is deeper. It seems someone committed those temp files. They should not be in the repository in the first place.